# Get the files under each git commit for git mail

Tags: git, email

I am trying to set up a mailing client that triggers an email every time a git push is made to the central repo. So I have copied the script from https://github.com/zma/usefulscripts/blob/master/script/post-receive .

Here is the mail I receive for a push.

```
 The project "My-Engineering":

    The branch, master has been updated
       via  e6693c90f2296a8df3bfcb13735cde069aababcd (commit)
       via  4e7e0176605a22b698e80f46b774abb1e721abcd (commit)
      from  c14285610f07ea8cd6613f5205d10a6fbbdbabcd (commit)


- Log -----------------------------------------------------------------
commit e6693c90f2296a8df3bfcb13735cde069aababcd
Author: NewBie<xxx@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 14 18:27:10 2015 +0530

hack.txt commit

commit 4e7e0176605a22b698e80f46b774abb1e721abcd
Author: NewBie<xxx@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 14 18:26:47 2015 +0530

help txt modified

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Summary of changes:
help.txt  | 1 +
hack.txt | 1 +
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)

--
My-Engineering
```

What I am trying to do is , for every commit I have to `display the files that have been added/modified/deleted only  under that commit` . 
Example :-

```
The project "My-Engineering":

    The branch, master has been updated
       via  e6693c90f2296a8df3bfcb13735cde069aababcd (commit)
       via  4e7e0176605a22b698e80f46b774abb1e721abcd (commit)
      from  c14285610f07ea8cd6613f5205d10a6fbbdbabcd (commit)


- Log -----------------------------------------------------------------
commit e6693c90f2296a8df3bfcb13735cde069aababcd
Author: NewBie<xxx@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 14 18:27:10 2015 +0530

   Files affected
A       hack.txt     #In this commit only hack.txt and new.txt have been committed
M       new.txt
    hack.txt commit

commit 4e7e0176605a22b698e80f46b774abb1e721abcd
Author: NewBie<xxx@abc.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 14 18:26:47 2015 +0530

Files affected
M       new.txt #In this commit only new.txt has been commmited
    help txt modified

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Summary of changes:
help.txt  | 1 +
hack.txt | 1 +
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)

--
My-Engineering
```

So I modified the piece of code in the script from the above link in the following way :-

```
show_new_revisions()
{

    if [ "$change_type" = create ]
    then
        # Show all revisions exclusive to this (new) branch.
        revspec=$newrev
    else
        # Branch update; show revisions not part of $oldrev.
        revspec=$oldrev..$newrev
    fi

    other_branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ |
    grep -F -v $refname)
    git rev-parse --not $other_branches |

    msg_count=0;
    git rev-list --pretty --stdin $revspec |
    while read onerev
    do
        # eval $(printf "$custom_showrev" onerev: $onerev)
        (( msg_count+=1 ))
        echo $msg_count
        if [ $msg_count == 5 ]
        then
            emailsubject="$onerev"
            echo "Files affected"
            git diff $oldrev..$newrev --name-status    #### Added this command 
            echo "$emailsubject" > "$emailsubject_tmp_file"
        fi
        echo "$onerev"
    done
}
```

But `git diff $oldrev..$newrev --name-status` works fine only if I have two commits under a push. If I have more than 2 commits then for every commit I need to do `git diff $current_rev --name-status` . 
For this I need to add this piece of code

```
 for rev in $(git rev-list $newrev..$oldrev)
    do
        echo "    $rev "
    done
```

But I am unable to add it and get this working.
Can anyone please help me fix this problem . Or suggest if there is any other better way to display changes only in that particular commit in a push with multiple commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this should help

```
 show_new_revisions()
    {
        # This shows all log entries that are not already covered by
        # another ref - i.e. commits that are now accessible from this
        # ref that were previously not accessible
        # (see generate_update_branch_email for the explanation of this
        # command)

        # Revision range passed to rev-list differs for new vs. updated
        # branches.
        if [ "$change_type" = create ]
        then
            # Show all revisions exclusive to this (new) branch.
            revspec=$newrev
        else
            # Branch update; show revisions not part of $oldrev.
            revspec=$oldrev..$newrev
        fi

        for i in $(git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev)
        do
            echo " "
            git show --name-status $i
            echo " "
        done
    }
```